# Reminder notifications are not properly synchronized with time

Tags: android, kotlin

I wrote an application that shows notifications with reminders for the date and time selected by the user. Notifications appear, but not at the selected time. I suspect there is some time synchronization error. I set the appropriate time on the elumator for my zone (+1), but I have the impression that previously set reminders appear randomly in time, because I do not see any relationship between them. If you see any solution to this problem, I would be very grateful!

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.DatePicker
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TimePicker
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var btnSetReminder: Button
    private lateinit var etReminderText: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnSetReminder = findViewById(R.id.btnSetReminder)
        etReminderText = findViewById(R.id.etReminderText)
    }

    fun showDateTimePicker(view: View) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val initialYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val initialMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val initialDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val initialHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val initialMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(this, { _, year, month, day ->
            val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(this, { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
                setReminder(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)
            }, initialHour, initialMinute, true)
            timePickerDialog.show()
        }, initialYear, initialMonth, initialDay)

        datePickerDialog.show()
    }

    private fun setReminder(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(year, month, day, hourOfDay, minute)


        if (calendar.timeInMillis > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val intent = Intent(this, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("REMINDER_TEXT", etReminderText.text.toString())
            intent.putExtra("REMINDER_TIME", calendar.timeInMillis)


            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent)
            Toast.makeText(this, "notification set an: ${calendar.time}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "entre date from the future", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

ReminderReceiver.kt

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2

import android.app.Notification
import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import com.example.kalendarz_2.R

class ReminderReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d("ReminderReceiver", "Received reminder broadcast")
        val reminderText = intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_TEXT") ?: "No contet notification"
        val reminderTime = intent?.getLongExtra("REMINDER_TIME", 0) ?: 0

        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

        if (reminderTime > currentTime) {
            showReminderNotification(context, reminderText)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "PNotification: $reminderText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun showReminderNotification(context: Context?, reminderText: String) {
        val notificationManager =
            context?.getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)

        val notificationChannelId = "channel_id"
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context!!, notificationChannelId)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Content of notification: $reminderText")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(notificationChannelId)
        }

        notificationManager?.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

ReminderService.kt

```
package com.example.kalendarz_2

import android.app.*
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import java.util.*

class ReminderService : Service() {

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("ReminderService", "Reminder service started")
        showReminderNotification(intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_TEXT") ?: "no reminder content")


        return START_STICKY
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun showReminderNotification(reminderText: String) {

        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)


        val notificationChannelId = "channel_id"
        val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(this, notificationChannelId)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Content notification: $reminderText")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setAutoCancel(true)


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannelId = "channel_id"
            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                notificationChannelId,
                "Notifications",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(notificationChannelId)
        }


        notificationManager?.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kalendarz_2">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Kalendarz_2">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"> <!-- Ustawienie android:exported na true dla launcher activity -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".ReminderService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <receiver android:name=".ReminderReceiver" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You're not using an [exact alarm](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule#exact)

Comment: What is an exact alarm? What I should change?

Comment: I fixed this error, Thank u very much, but notifications appear with incorrect content. do you have an idea how to solve it?